# schema is not a construktor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
}
});
```

save

```
const newUser = new userSchema({ name: body.name, password: body.password });

newUser.save((err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)});
});
```

It gives me error: userSchema is not a constructor

Comment: The message is exactly right; userSchema is not a constructor.  It is a `const`; that's how you've defined it.

Comment: What you probably meant to do is call `userSchema.someMethod()`